# How to share a youtube video in twitter using php

Tags: php, twitter, youtube

I do have a page in which i have a `embedded YouTube video`.I would like to share this video in the corresponding users `twitter` account.Is there any means by which I could share this `YouTube` video in a `twitter` account.?Could I perform this process using some `API`..?Hope someone could really help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really provided any information which is indicative of your current set-up, but generally speaking adding Tweet button is extremely easy using the Twitter API.

Twitter actually provides a great button generator which you can use to generate the relevant HTML embed code [here](https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons).

You can read more about the Tweet button API [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)

Comment: tanx for the reply @patopop007.Could i really embed it and show it in the twitter account..??

Comment: No problem! Usually, people tend to just share the link with a tweet. Although I have not tried them myself, you could hypothetically use [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards) to embed the video.